# Get result to python variable after executing R script

Tags: python, r, subprocess

i am executing a r script from python and i want the output to be available in  the python variable. how can i do that?

python script:

```
import subprocess 

def runR(id, lat, long):
    value = subprocess.popen("C:/R/R-3.2.0/bin/Rscript      E:/Personal/python/script.R --args "+id+" "+lat+" "+long , shell=True)
    print value
```

R script :

```
a = "Hello";
```

I want Hello to be availabe on the python variable value.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Comment: why not define the value variable by itself so it will be available for the session instead of in the function?>

Comment: Cheaters way: Run the program, write data to a local text file, then access that file from Python :P

Comment: That's how I once tried transferring info from Python to PHP/JavaScript

Comment: This SO post looks like it answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846891/python-piping-output-between-two-subprocesses

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`rpy2`](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.5/html/introduction.html):

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

robjects.r('''
a = "Hello";
''')
a = robjects.r['a']
```

As an alternative, you could rewrite your R script so that it would dump its result to stdout in some well-known format such as json, then run it using `subprocess` module, and parse the result:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
import subprocess

id, lat, long = 1, 40, 74 
out = subprocess.check_output(r"C:\R\R-3.2.0\bin\Rscript.exe "
                              r"E:\path\to\script.R --args "
                               "{id} {lat} {long}".format(**vars()))
data = json.loads(out.decode('utf-8'))
```

Note: no need to use `shell=True` on Windows if you use the full path to the executable here.

Answer (score -1):

You can modify the following example by your need.

**a.py:**

```
print 'hello'
```

**b.py:**

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.check_output(["python", "a.py"])
print result.strip() + 'world'
```

**Output of b.py:**

```
helloworld
```

Comment: r script is just an example that i gave. I need to execute the r code and get the answer in python

Comment: You could run the program, write all the data to a text file, then access that file from Python