# Is it possible to solve with python to run two executable and they can communicate each other (stdin/stdout)?

Tags: python, redirect, stdout, stdin

I have two executable e.g A.exe, B.exe.
Is it possible with python subprocess popen to the two executable communicate each other through stdin/stdout:

```
A = Popen("A.exe",...,stdin=B.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
B = Popen("B.exe",...,stdin=A.stdout, stdout=PIPE) ?
```

(where A.exe contains print/scanf pairs, and B.exe the scanf/printfs.)

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, although `pexpect` and have both run and do whatever you wish to put from one to another ?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846891/python-piping-output-between-two-subprocesses

Answer (score 0):

try `Popen.communicate` it takes a parameter `input` with the text to send to a subprocess and returns a tuple `(stdout_data, stderr_data)`

```
(output, error) = A.communicate(input="send to a")
```