# Piped shell script that needs user input isn't printing its output

Tags: python, django

I am executing a shell script through a pipe in Python as follows:

```
def(request,self):
    args_str1 = "flexiserver/build/svnenv.sh -j 'svntasktag.pl ss_fvnteste'"
    args1 = shlex.split(args_str1)
    pi = subprocess.Popen(args1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    print("***** Before out err *****")
    out, err = pi.communicate()
    print(" OUT is %s " , out)

    context = {'out':out, 'err':err}
    req_context = RequestContext(request)
    return render_to_response(
        'pai_app/create_tag.html', context, context_instance=req_context)
```

This script is waiting for user input like 'i', 'm', 'c' like arguments. Until the user gives any input it is not printing and not showing in webui.

My question is, is there any possibility to run such Perl or shell scripts in webui itself? Or is there any other resolution for the above problem? Could anyone help me in this as i am struck.

Comment: Can you edit the perl script to remove the need to read in from stdin?

Comment: Can you redirect something to the stdin of the script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080402/python-subprocess-module-how-do-i-give-input-to-the-first-of-series-of-piped-co

Answer (score 0):

While your Python code is opening a pipe to a shell script that takes as argument something that looks like it's a Perl script, this question is really related to pipes in Python.

> This script is waiting for user input like 'i', 'm', 'c' like arguments.

You can send an 'i' to the process using `pi.communicate('i')`.

Comment: I added as pi.communicate('i') but no luck. still it is awaiting for input pi = subprocess.Popen(args1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                    out, err = pi.communicate('i')
                   print(" OUT is %s " , out)
                   context = {'out':out, 'err':err}
           
                   return render_to_response('pai_app/create_tag.html', {'out':out, 'err':err}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

Comment: You understand, then, that there's something you're not saying.

Comment: is it possible to run the complete script including user input in the html form I mean like as we normally run in linux console ?