# invoking pipe command with Popen in Python

Tags: python, unix, subprocess

What is the correct way to invoke a command containing multiple pipes to `Popen` so that its output can be read? I tried:

`Popen(shlex.split("mycmd arg1 | mysecondcmd - | thirdcmd -", stdout=PIPE)")`

But I don't believe `shlex.split` is right here. What's the correct syntax?

Comment: For one thing, you're passing `stdout=PIPE` as an argument to `shlex.split`, not to the `Popen` constructor. For another, you've got an odd number of `"` characters; presumably it's the last one that's extraneous. Also, if you want to use shell features, you have to pass `shell=True`. (You usually don't want to spawn a shell to pipe the commands together, but if you want to, you can.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [link several Popen commands with pipes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389662/link-several-popen-commands-with-pipes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few options -- You can pass `shell=True`:

```
Popen('command1 | command2 | command3',shell=True)
```

Or, you can break it up into a bunch of `Popen` calls hooking their stdout to the next Popen's stdin as demonstrated in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline).

Answer (score 3):

Using the [sh module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/sh), pipes become function composition:

```
import sh
output = sh.thirdcmd(sh.mysecondcmd(sh.mycmd("arg1")))
```

---

If you want to do it with subprocess without `shell = True`, there is an [example in the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) which shows how to write shell pipelines using `subprocess.Popen`. Note that you are supposed to close the `proc.stdout`s so that `SIGPIPE`s can be received properly:

```
import subprocess
proc1 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('mycmd arg1'), stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
proc2 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('mysecondcmd'), stdin = proc1.PIPE,
                         stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
proc3 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('thirdcmd'), stdin = proc2.PIPE,
                         stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

# Allow proc1 to receive a SIGPIPE if proc2 exits.
proc1.stdout.close()
# Allow proc2 to receive a SIGPIPE if proc3 exits.
proc2.stdout.close()
out, err = proc3.communicate()
```

This might look like a lot more work than using `shell = True`. The reason why you might want to avoid `shell = True` is because [it can be a security risk](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) (page down to the "Warning" box), especially if you are running a command supplied by a (potentially malicious) user.