# Trouble with subprocess.Popen parsing of the command list; pipe not being sent out correctly

Tags: python

When I run the following command in the interpreter

```
infile_intersect = subprocess.Popen(['cut', '-f', '1,2,3,4,5', infile, r'|', 'intersectBed', '-a', 'stdin', '-b', bound_motif, '-wo', r'|', 'sort', '-k', '1,1', '-k', '2,2n', '|uniq'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

I get the error `cut: invalid option -- a` but when I do a space join of the list it seems fine

```
>>> ' '.join(['cut', '-f', '1,2,3,4,5', infile, r'|', 'intersectBed', '-a', 'stdin', '-b', bound_motif, '-wo', r'|', 'sort', '-k', '1,1', '-k', '2,2n', '|uniq'])
'cut -f 1,2,3,4,5 test.bed | intersectBed -a stdin -b ENCODE.tf.bound.union.bed -wo | sort -k 1,1 -k 2,2n |uniq'
```

Seemingly the pipe isn't being sent out correctly, but I am unsure why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you pipe using subprocess, using a `|` with the list input form is invalid. You should either pass the full string to it and use `shell=True` or pipe like the way I've done in the example below:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(['cat', 'abc1'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p1 = subprocess.Popen(['uniq', '-c'], stdin=p.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> print p1.communicate()[0]
      3 word1
      1 word3
      1 word4
      1 word5
```

Using string and `shell=True`

```
>>> print subprocess.Popen('cat abc1 | uniq -c', shell=True,
                                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
      3 word1
      1 word3
      1 word4
      1 word5
```

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

> Warning Invoking the system shell with `shell=True` can be a security
>   hazard if combined with untrusted input.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to [execute a shell pipeline](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline), if your input is trusted, the quickest way is to pass in `shell=True`

```
subprocess.Popen(r'''cut -f 1,2,3,4,5 test.bed | intersectBed -a stdin -b ENCODE.tf.bound.union.bed -wo | sort -k 1,1 -k 2,2n |uniq''', shell=True).communicate()
```

If your input is untrustworthy, you are going to have to chain several `Popen` objects, one per each command from the pipeline, take a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7389857/753731)