# Popen subprocess.PIPE and its uses

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I know that this question may have been asked a lot but I am still not really getting it.
Reading from this related [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389662/link-several-popen-commands-with-pipes), I can understand why there is a need to add `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` at the end of the sentence so that the output result can be used into the next Popen.

Tried looking online, but I garner little to no knowledge about it as the ones I found are in the form of a documentation.

But if I am not using the output, is it really necessary to put `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` at the end? 
I tried executing it with and without the use of it, and it is still giving me the expected results that I wanted.

Hence what are the big differences whether `subprocess.PIPE` is present or not?

```
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.communicate()
```

Answer (score 7):

Without subprocess.PIPE the output of command would be printed on STDOUT and process.communicate() should return None.
Which python version are you using?

Can you paste the output?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, even as I tried this simple example `process = subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'Hello World!'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` as you have mentioned, the differences is between a `None` print out. But still I am getting the result `Hello World!` printed, is that not considered an output?

Comment: Without subprocess.PIPE you wont be able to take the output returned by the command in a variable. That's the difference. Somewhat like print "Hello World" vs return "Hello World"

Comment: Ok thanks... I am still somewhat 'un-convinced'? or rather not being able to see the logic how it is exactly working... Will tried to see it in the "Hello World" vs return "Hello World" example

Comment: Let me try one more time: Let's say in your python script you have to write the output of "ps aux" (shell command) into a file. The file write part has to be in python not in shell, so you would need the result of "ps aux" in a variable that you can perform file.write(var) with. To do this, you have to set STDOUT --> subprocess.PIPE

Comment: Thanks for the info. Kinda get what you mean but I think I may need to find more examples to work with, to drill it into my brain

Comment: @yan: the correct way to write the output of `ps aux` is to redirect the output to file directly **without** subprocess.PIPE e.g., `with open('output', 'wb', 0) as file: subprocess.check_call(['ps', 'aux'], stdout=file)`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't read/write to the corresponding pipe then you should **not** use `subprocess.PIPE`. It may stall the child process if the corresponding OS pipe buffer fills up.

Use `subprocess.PIPE` if you want to [get the output of the child process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12606327/4279) (or pass input) as a string (variable) or just call `subprocess.check_output()` that does it for you internally.

Use `subprocess.PIPE` if you want to pass `process.stdout` as stdin to another process (to [emulate `a | b`  shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16709666/4279)).

If you want to ignore the output; you could [redirect it to DEVNULL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11270665/4279). You could redirect it to a file (or to anything with a valid `.fileno()` e.g., [sockets on Unix](https://gist.github.com/zed/7454768)).