# Python: piping Requests image argument to stdin

Tags: python, arguments, pipe, stdin, python-requests

I am trying to send arguments to a subprocess' stdin. In my case, it is an image downloaded with Requsts.

Here is my code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
img = requests.get(url, stream=True)
i = img.raw.read()
proc = subprocess.Popen(['icat', '-'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
proc.communicate(i)
#proc.stdin.write(i) # I tried this too
```

Unfortunately, the subprocess does nothing, and I get no errors. What is wrong with my code, and is there a cross-platform solution?

Comment: You are not actually streaming anything here, so you can just use `img.content`. You are also ignoring the *output* from `proc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`icat`](https://github.com/atextor/icat) queries your terminal to see what dimensions to resize the image to, but a pipe is not suitable as a terminal and you end up with empty output. The help information from `icat` states:

> Big images are automatically resized to your terminal width, unless with the -k option.

When you use the `-k` switch output is produced.

There is no need to stream here, you can just leave the loading to `requests` and pass in the response body, un-decoded:

```
img = requests.get(url)
proc = subprocess.Popen(['icat', '-k', '-'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate(img.content)
```

The `stderr` value will be empty, but `stdout` should contain transformed image data (ANSI colour escapes):

```
>>> import requests
>>> import subprocess
>>> url = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/24780fb6df85a943c7aea0402c843737'
>>> img = requests.get(url)
>>> from subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen(['icat', '-k', '-'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
>>> stdout, stderr = proc.communicate(img.content)
>>> len(stdout)
77239
>>> stdout[:20]
'\x1b[38;5;15m\x1b[48;5;15m'
```

Comment: I'm using this [icat](https://github.com/atextor/icat), and the image still doesn't show up.

Comment: @octosquidopus: that command requires a suitable terminal. A pipe is *not* a suitable terminal.

Comment: @octosquidopus: hrm, I may be incorrect about `icat` here; I see that they also offer `> imagedata.txt` options. I have no problems using `cat -` to pipe an image through a subprocess however.

Comment: Really? Bummer. In that case, I suppose you've answered my original question and I thank you for the clear example, but is there a way of using [icat](https://github.com/atextor/icat) with Python?

Comment: @octosquidopus: BTW, I see that when you use `icat -`, the image data is [written to a temporary file](https://github.com/atextor/icat/blob/master/icat.c#L269-L280); IIRC you wanted to avoid that.

Comment: @octosquidopus: can you try `icat -k -`? I see that the terminal is only queried to get the image size. Alternatively, set `-x` and `-y` to the output dimensions you want.

Comment: @octosquidopus: I'll need to install XQuartz to test locally, I'll see about trying that later tonight.

Comment: OK, I'll try `icat -k -` right away. Wow, you're very helpful! I wanted to avoid writin to a temporary file needlessly, but I didn't know that `icat` was doing it behind my back. It's fine, I suppose.

Comment: Weird. My `len(stdout)` and `len(img.content)` don't match with `icat -k -`.

Comment: @octosquidopus that's no surprise;,`icat` transforms the image data to an ANSI sequence.

Comment: @octosquidopus: confirmed that `-k` fixes your issue.

Comment: Notes to self: 1) add `print stdout` at the end. 2) buy Martijn Pieters a beer someday.

Comment: I am struggling to make two pipes communicate. How can I resize `url` with `convert` before piping its output to `icat`?

Comment: @octosquidopus: [How do I use subprocess.Popen to connect multiple processes by pipes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/295459) and [link several Popen commands with pipes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7389662)

Comment: What I am trying to do seems considerably more complex than what I can glean from the examples given on these questions, and I cannot figure out the subprocess.Popen docs either. Should I edit my question here, or open a new question instead? I would really need some sort of in-depth explanation of the steps involved, as it currently feels mindbogglingly complex and I have tried everything.

Comment: @octosquidopus you'd create a new question for that.