# Subshell in python subprocess

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

Within a python script I need to launch a command such as

```
kill $(ps aux | grep httpd | awk '{print $2}')
```

Using **subprocess**
I have tried to split the command using a function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/29755431/1355628)

The function is fine with simple commands with pipe but unfortunately with the one above it does not seem to work (the return code seems to be completely random...)

Thanks is advance

Comment: What's your end goal here, do you want to kill a running process using python ?

Comment: I need to handle multiple ways to stop a process. Sometimes a simple "service xxx stop" is fine but for some processes it is not enough (kill needed)

Answer (score 5):

[`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) takes an optional `shell=True` argument, which will run your command in a subshell.
Please do read the [Security Considerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations) however, if you're handling user input.

Another (better, imo) solution, would be to use the [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil/) package and `os.kill`, like this:

```
import psutil
processes = [p for p in psutil.pids() if 'httpd' in psutil.Process(p).name()]
for process in processes:
    os.kill(...)
```

Comment: I have tried something like : 

`cmd = "kill $(ps aux | grep proces[s] | awk '{print $2}');rm -f /var/lock/process && service process start"
pop = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
pop.wait()
print "return code is : %d" % pop.returncode`

Executing the command in a bash is fine, but within python it results in a failure :
"return code is -15" (instead of 0)