# checking for a string from shell output

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system

I am trying to check for information on Linux server,if it has certain disks named 'ocr'.
So I have run a shell command and capture the output in a text file.
Then I will search for the string in the file.But this below script doest work.

```
import os
myCmd = os.popen('ls /dev/asm|grep ocr').read()
print(myCmd)

with open('myCmd') as f:
    if 'ocr' in f.read():
        print("RAC server")
```

Comment: what is open('myCmd') ? you have a file named myCmd?

Comment: Note, you could use two popen commands to handle the pipe to grep https://stackoverflow.com/a/7389857/2308683

Comment: I feel like you should just do `os.listdir("/dev/asm")`

Comment: myCmd is has the output of the shell script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and capture the output in a text file

You've saved it in a string variable, then you're trying to open and read a file named myCmd. These likely have different content because it's not clear where you've actually written any files

You don't need a file for the logic of that code

```
if 'ocr' in myCmd:
    print("RAC server")
```

Also, you really shouldn't be using shell commands if you don't have to

```
for f in os.listdir("/dev/asm"):
    if "ocr" in f:
        print("RAC server")
        break
```

Comment: can I add a else clause: