# Python - how to execute shell commands with pipe, but without 'shell=True'?

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

I have a case to want to execute the following shell command in Python and get the output,

```
echo This_is_a_testing | grep -c test
```

I could use this python code to execute the above shell command in python,

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output("echo This_is_a_testing | grep -c test", shell=True)
'1\n'
```

However, as I **do not want to use the "shell=True" option**, I tried the following python code,

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> p1 = subprocess.Popen(["echo", "This_is_a_testing"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p2 = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "-c", "test"], stdin=p1.stdout)
>>> p1.stdout.close()
>>> p2.communicate()
(None, None)
```

I wonder why the output is "None" as I have referred to the descriptions in the webpage : http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE

Had I missed some points in my code ? Any suggestion / idea ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: related: [How do I use subprocess.Popen to connect multiple processes by pipes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/295459/4279)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From the manual:

> to get anything other than None in the result tuple, you need to give
>   stdout=PIPE and/or stderr=PIPE

```
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "-c", "test"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 44):

```
>>> import subprocess

>>> mycmd=subprocess.getoutput('df -h | grep home | gawk \'{ print $1 }\' | cut -d\'/\' -f3')

>>> mycmd 

'sda6'

>>>
```

Comment: it uses the shell internally. OP explicitly said: *"I do not want to use the "shell=True" option"*

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I'm looking for when searching for "***how to execute shell commands with pipes***" in Python.

Comment: I had to use commands.getoutput instead of subprocess.getoutput for this to work

Comment: Isn't is `subprocess.check_output()`?

Comment: Doesn't exist in Python 2.7, does in Python 3.6.6

Comment: Holy cr@p this was helpful! I had been wracking my brain with sed, perl, awk, node, python, etc... trying to do a string substitution where the replacement contains the output of piped shell commands for each match.


[My example gist](https://gist.github.com/wickkidd/7d9c87d7459b58f1e0a6df71906cb234)

Comment: You can also do `subprocess.getstatusoutput` which returns a tuple, where the first element is the exit code.

Answer (score 40):

Please look here:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> p1 = subprocess.Popen(["echo", "This_is_a_testing"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p2 = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "-c", "test"], stdin=p1.stdout)
>>> 1
p1.stdout.close()
>>> p2.communicate()
(None, None)
>>>
```

here you get 1 as output after you write `p2 = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "-c", "test"], stdin=p1.stdout)`, Do not ignore this output in the context of your question.

If this is what you want, then pass `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` as argument to the second `Popen`:

```
>>> p1 = subprocess.Popen(["echo", "This_is_a_testing"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p2 = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "test"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p2.communicate()
('This_is_a_testing\n', None)
>>>
```

Comment: Now I know that for `p2.communicate()` to work, I must add `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` in the code `p2 = ...`. Thanks.

Comment: How I can get error if it happens in p1 result? Here is my question, can you help with it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467105/how-to-catch-ping-error-with-python

Answer (score 6):

While the accepted answer is correct/working, another option would be to use the `Popen.communicate()` method to pass something to a process' stdin:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> p2 = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "-c", "test"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p2.communicate("This_is_a_testing")
('1\n', None)
>>> print p2.returncode
0
>>>>
```

This resolves the need to execute another command just to redirect it's output, if the output is already known in the python script itself.

However `communicate` has the side-effect, that it waits for the process to terminate. If asynchronous execution is needed/desired using two processes might be the better option.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is similar to mentioned earlier, with little formatting. I wanted to get exactly same output as normal shell command with pipe on python 3.

```
import subprocess

p1 = subprocess.Popen(["ls", "-l", "."], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "May"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)


for s in (str(p2.communicate())[2:-10]).split('\\n'):
    print(s)
```