# Adding pipe symbol in Python command

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04, zenity

I am trying to write a script to copy files from one flash drive to another using Python along with Zenity UI. Variables `Sorz_star` and `Desz` contains path to two flash drives.

```
subprocess.call('cp -R %s %s |zenity --progress --text "Copying" --pulsate --auto-close'%(Sorz_star,Desz), shell=True)
```

This works fine in terminal but when I use this command in my `copy.py` file it shows this error

```
sh: 2: Syntax error: "|" unexpected
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - how to execute shell commands with pipe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393425/python-how-to-execute-shell-commands-with-pipe)

Comment: @PatrickMcLaren But that wont work with the above said scenario i already tried that...Thats why i posted this

Comment: What's the value of `Sorz_star` and `Desz`?

Comment: @DavidK.Hess Sorz_star="/media/Flash1" Desz="/media/Flash2"

Comment: I bet one or both of those ends with a newline. Use `.strip()` on them to remove it.

Comment: Thank you @DavidK.Hess that was the issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One or both of the substituted variables probably ends with a newline. Use `.strip()` on them to remove it.