# How to catch ping error with Python?

Tags: python, ping

Here is my simple example:

```
import subprocess
cmd   = 'ping something.local -c 1'
tail  = 'tail -n 3'

ping = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(' '), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
tail = subprocess.Popen(tail.split(' '), stdin=ping.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
ping.stdout.close()
out, err = tail.communicate()
print 'Print values:'
print out
print err
```

And here is the output example of script:

```
[~/python]$ python ping_stats.py
ping: cannot resolve tpeo.local: Unknown host
Print values:

None
```

So, my variables `out` and `err` are "empty", but I need a `ping: cannot resolve tpeo.local: Unknown host` error message. How I can get it?

Comment: Use os.system instead of Popen. And then check the response code

Comment: So, is it impossible to do with subprocess.Popen?

Answer (score 0):

Just capture standard error in the result via `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`.
Also, use [shlex.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) rather than `string.split(' ')`:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

cmd   = 'ping something.local -c 1'

ping = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
out = ping.communicate()[0]
```

Or:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

cmd   = 'ping unknown -c 1'

ping = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = ping.communicate()

print out
print err
```

Comment: How about pipe `| tail -n 3` for your example?