# Cant use grep in subprocess command

Tags: python, grep, subprocess

I'm having a problem with my subprocess command, I like to grep out the lines that match with "Online" line.

```
def run_command(command):
    p = subprocess.Popen(command,shell=False,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    return iter(p.stdout.readline, b'')

command = 'mosquitto_sub -u example -P example -t ITT/# -v | grep "Online" '.split()
for line in run_command(command):
    print(line)
```

But I will get an error

```
Error: Unknown option '|'.



Use 'mosquitto_sub --help' to see usage.
```

But when running with linux shell

```
user@server64:~/Pythoniscriptid$ mosquitto_sub -u example -P example  -t ITT/# -v | grep "Online"
ITT/C5/link Online
ITT/IoT/tester55/link Online
ITT/ESP32/TEST/link Online
```

I also tried `shell = True`, but with no success, because I will get another error, that dosen't recognize the topic `ITT/#`

```
Error: You must specify a topic to subscribe to.



Use 'mosquitto_sub --help' to see usage.
```

The "possible dublicate" didn't help me at all, So I think I'm having a different problem. I tried to change code to this, put in not getting any return

```
def run_command(command,command2):
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    p2 = subprocess.Popen(command2,stdin=p1.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    return iter(p2.stdout.readline,'')



command = 'mosquitto_sub -u example -P example -t ITT/# -v'.split()
command2 = 'grep Online'.split()

#subprocess.getoutput(command)

for line in run_command(command,command2):
    print(line)
```

Comment: Try to add `executable="/bin/bash"` to `Popen`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - how to execute shell commands with pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393425/python-how-to-execute-shell-commands-with-pipe)

Comment: @Maroun getting error / usr / bin / test: / usr / bin / test: binary can not be started

Comment: @joppich I think he kinda had a diffrent problem

Comment: I need to use this function, since my output string is long

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you split the text, the list will look like

```
['mosquitto_sub', ..., 'ITT/#', '-v', '|', 'grep', '"Online"']
```

When you pass this list to subprocess.Popen, a literal `'|'` will be one of the arguments to mosquitto_sub.

If you use `shell=True`, you must escape any special characters like `#` in the command, for instance with double quotes:

```
import subprocess
command = 'echo -e "ITT/#\\ni am Online\\nbar Online\\nbaz" | grep "Online" '
p = subprocess.Popen(
    command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    print(line)
```

Alternatively, connect the pipes as you wrote, but make sure to iterate until `b''`, not `u''`:

```
import subprocess

def run_command(command, command2):
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    p2 = subprocess.Popen(command2,stdin=p1.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    return iter(p2.stdout.readline, b'')

command = ['echo', '-e', 'ITT/#\\ni am Online\\nbar Online\\nbaz']
command2 = 'grep Online'.split()

for line in run_command(command,command2):
    print(line)
```