# How to get result from grep with Python

Tags: python

I am trying to get output from grep with wildcard

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '002HQV', 'test.*'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  
shell=True)
res = proc.stdout.readlines()
print(res)
```

but get the following error

```
2.4.3 (#1, Jun 11 2009, 14:09:37)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)]
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...  
Try `grep --help' for more information.
[]
```

Is it wrong with my grep syntax?

The following works

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '*'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

and

```
os.system("grep 02HQV test.*")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - how to execute shell commands with pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393425/python-how-to-execute-shell-commands-with-pipe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `shell=True` your should use a string, see [subprocess.call using string vs using list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109665/subprocess-call-using-string-vs-using-list)

You can avoid using a shell and still use a list by using the `glob` standard library module:

```
import subprocess
import glob

command = ['grep', '002HQV']
command.extend(glob.glob('test.*'))
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
res = proc.stdout.readlines()
print(res)
```

Comment: but how to explain `proc = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '*'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)`  works?

Comment: @HsingYi - the `*` gets ignored, it is the same as `subprocess.Popen(['ls'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)`.  The default for `ls` is the current directory `.`, the `*` shell expansion is all the file names in the current directory, which is what you get on both.

Answer (score 0):

In general I'd try to avoid launching subprocesses for things that are simple string manipulation and straightforward file I/O.  That's especially true when you start getting into actively dangerous things like `subprocess.call(shell=True)`.  You can use the [glob module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to do the filename expansion and then loop through the files.

Here's one example:

```
import glob
res = []
for fn in glob.glob('test.*'):
    with open(fn, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
          if '002HQV' in line:
              res.append(line)
print(res)
```