# python subprocess.run with awk failing

Tags: python, awk, subprocess

**My function:**

```
def run(cmd = ""):
    sp = subprocess.run(shlex.split(cmd), shell = False, capture_output = True)
    pprint(sp)
    print(sp.stdout.decode("utf-8", 'ignore'))
```

This function was working normally. Then I suddenly came across `awk` and it gave me an error.

Command passed to the function:

```
run(cmd = "ssh myserver \"tail -10 server.log | awk '{print $7}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head\"")
```

To simplify this further,

```
run(cmd = "ssh myserver \"tail -10 server.log | awk '{print $7}'\"")
```

Mark the ssh above. All the commands passed to ssh needs to run on the remote and not on local machine. Hence multiple subprocess is not gonna help. The error thrown for both of the above commands is

```
awk: line 2: missing } near end of file
```

Both the above commands work fine from terminal. 
I suspected, pipe (|) or single quotes (' ') might be the culprit. But the below code works fine.

```
run(cmd = "ssh myserver \"tail -10 server.log | grep something\"")

run(cmd = "ssh myserver \"tail -10 server.log | grep 'something'\"")
```

Can anyone help me out with `awk` in the above?

The associated question mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393425/python-how-to-execute-shell-commands-with-pipe-but-without-shell-true) is not related and won't help in my case as the moment `tail -10 server.log` changes to `tail -10000 server.log` or `cat server.log`, multiple subprocess will try to download the whole content of the `server.log` from the remote server which might be in GBs and then process the output while the whole command of

```
ssh myserver cat server.log | awk '{print $7}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head
```

might be 15-20 lines.

Since it's used with ssh which as mentioned in the comments: concatenates multiple arguments, intentionally multiple subprocess haven't been used.

I tried multiple snippets after suggestions from comment which doesn't work and throw same or similar error as mentioned above. Both the snippet in the question and suggestions work for normal scenarios and only fail for `awk` with the above mentioned error.

Try 1:

```
cmd = "ssh myserver \"tail -10 server.log | awk '{print $7}'\""
sp = subprocess.run(shlex.split(cmd), shell = False, capture_output = True)
pprint(sp)
```

Try 2:

```
cmd = ["ssh", "myserver", "tail -10 server.log | awk '{print $7}'"]
sp = subprocess.run(cmd, shell = False, capture_output = True)
pprint(sp)
```

Try 3:
(Exact suggestion from the comment)

```
cmd = ['ssh', 'myserver', '''tail -10 server.log | awk '{print $7}'''']
sp = subprocess.run(cmd, shell = False, capture_output = True)
pprint(sp)
```

Try 4:

```
cmd = ["ssh", "myserver", """tail -10 server.log | awk '{print $7}'"""]
sp = subprocess.run(cmd, shell = False, capture_output = True)
pprint(sp)
```

Comment: Don't use `cmd.split(" ")`. It's buggy and wrong, which is why `shlex.split()` exists instead (but better than that is specifying your commands an argv arrays instead of strings in the first place). And beyond that, for a pipeline, you need a separate subprocess for each piece of the pipeline (which is exactly what a shell does when you give it `foo | bar` -- it splits off one subprocess for `foo`, and a second one for `bar`; in Python terms, that means one `subprocess.Popen` for each piece).

Comment: See also https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline

Comment: That said, consider `run(['ssh', 'myserver', 'tail -10 server.log | grep something'])`, moving the `grep` to the remote side instead of trying to run it locally at all. (There are some security precautions needed if `something`, or `server.log`, or any other substring is provided by an untrusted source, by the way; but that's true regardless).

Comment: ...in practice, you might `from shlex import quote` and then `run(['ssh', 'myserver', f'tail -10 {quote(logfile)} | grep {quote(target)}'])`, assuming that `logfile='server.log'` and `target='something'` and that both of these are parameterized and subject to change; that way someone can't set `target=''' $(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)' '''` and then watch as your server deletes its home directory.

Comment: SSH is something of a special case here, because when it's given multiple arguments it just concatenates them together and joins them into a single command passed to the remote shell; so things can _look_ like they work with ssh even though they don't behave quite the same way they would if you were running the same command through a shell. It's a bad habit to be relying on that, though; much more reasonable to make your code's behavior explicit.

Comment: Since it's required to be used with ssh, multiple subprocess was not used. (Mentioned this in the edit.) And grep works fine with the code above. Just awk fails when passed with pipe.

Comment: Grep "works fine" but not in the way you might expect: it's being run _on the remote server_ not the local system as it would be if you passed the same command to a shell -- that's part of why I encourage _explicitly_ quoting the whole remote command, so readers who don't know the under-the-hood details don't misapprehend what's going on at runtime.

Comment: I told you, for good reasons, to run `['ssh', 'hostname', '''cat server.log | awk '{print $7}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head''']`. I'm not sure why this isn't serviceable as an answer. (Yes, we could go into _why_ a command with quotes and spaces within them that need to be literal rather than syntactic causes the original approach to break, but if "don't do that" solves the problem, then _the problem is solved_).

Comment: None of the options are working. Look at the edit 2 in the question. Is it possible to open the question and provide a working answer? Since the associated question meant to mark this a duplicate is not applicable with ```ssh```.

Comment: I honestly do not believe you when you claim that try 4 failed with the error `awk: line 2: missing } near end of file` -- at least, not if the server you're ssh'ing into is running a POSIX-compliant shell and a POSIX-compliant copy of awk.

Comment: f/e, I get perfectly normal/expected behavior with `subprocess.run(['ssh', 'localhost', """who | awk '{print $2}'"""], capture_output=True)` run on my own (MacOS) system. If you can provide a command someone _who isn't you_ (and doesn't have access to the private environment you're testing against) can run without changes to see a problem that isn't a duplicate, yes, I'll reopen the question.

Comment: (I should say, a POSIX-compliant shell, a POSIX-compliant awk, and no `ForceCommand` configured to override _how_ sshd invokes commands passed to the server; _something's_ going on here, clearly, but if it's something that's local to a server that nobody but you has access to, then that's not really a question we can answer).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for bearing with my questions. I see that ```subprocess.run(shlex.split("ssh localhost \"who | awk '{print $2}'\""), capture_output=True)``` is also working fine. But all of these are failing when going through a proxy jumpbox. Just that the ssh command with awk is running fine when executed from terminal even though it is going via jumpbox, but is errored out when run through subprocess. So wondering why the issue is with subprocess and not terminal (only when going via this jumpbox)?

Comment: Can you show me exactly _how_ you're going through the jumpbox? If it's with `-J` / `-o ProxyJump` that ought to be fine assuming standard openssh in the middle (if the jumpbox is an embedded system running an alternate sshd implementation, those can sometimes get dicey). Anything that does the expansion inside double quotes, though, could change `$2` to an empty string.

Comment: It's with ```-J```.  And if the issue might be with jumpbox, it'd have blocked the command when executed from the terminal as well. Not just the ```subprocess```. Lemme dice up what actually the ```subprocess```'s final command set and arguments are before they leave python.

Comment: This question can be closed. It was an issue specific to the ssh wrapper we have for jumpboxes. it replaces the ```$7``` no matter how I escape the $.