# python subprocess and mysqldump

Tags: python, subprocess, mysql

I know parts of this question have been asked before, but I have some related questions.

I'm trying to execute

```
mysqldump -u uname -ppassword --add-drop-database --databases databaseName | gzip > fileName
```

I'm potentially dumping a very large (200GB?) db.  Is that in itself a dumb thing to do?  I then want to send the zipped file over the network for storage, delete the local dump, and purge a couple of tables.

Anyway, I was using subprocess like this, because there doesn't seem to be a way to execute the entire original call without subprocess considering | to be a table name.:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

f = open(FILENAME, 'wb')
args = ['mysqldump', '-u', 'UNAME', '-pPASSWORD', '--add-drop-database', '--databases', 'DB']

p1 = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE)
P2 = Popen('gzip', stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=f)
p2.communicate()
```

but then I read that communicate caches the data in memory, which wouldn't work for me.  Is this true?

What I ended up doing for now is:

```
import gzip
subprocess.call(args, stdout=f)
f.close()

f = open(filename, 'rb')
zipFilename = filename + '.gz'
f2 = gzip.open(zipFilename, 'wb')
f2.writelines(f)
f2.close()
f.close()
```

of course this takes a million years, and I hate it.

My Questions: 
1. Can I use my first approach on a very large db?
2. Could I possibly pipe the output of mysqldump to a socket and fire it across the network and save it when it arrives, rather than sending a zipped file?

Thanks!

Comment: related: [How do I use subprocess.Popen to connect multiple processes by pipes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/295459/4279)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need communicate(). Its only there as a convenience method if you want to read stdout/stderr to completion. But since you are chaining the commands, they are doing that for you. Just wait for them to complete.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

args = ['mysqldump', '-u', 'UNAME', '-pPASSWORD', '--add-drop-database', '--databases', 'DB']

with open(FILENAME, 'wb', 0) as f:
    p1 = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE)
    p2 = Popen('gzip', stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=f)
p1.stdout.close() # force write error (/SIGPIPE) if p2 dies
p2.wait()
p1.wait()
```

Answer (score 3):

You are quite close to where you want:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

f = open(FILENAME, 'wb')
args = ['mysqldump', '-u', 'UNAME', '-pPASSWORD', '--add-drop-database', '--databases', 'DB']

p1 = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE)
```

Till here it is right.

```
p2 = Popen('gzip', stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
```

This one takes `p1`'s output and processes it. Afterwards we can (and should) immediately `p1.stdout.close()`.

Now we have a `p2.stdout` which can be read from and, without using a temporary file, send it via the network:

```
s = socket.create_connection(('remote_pc', port))
while True:
    r = p2.stdout.read(65536)
    if not r: break
    s.send(r)
```

Comment: Awesome.  I'll give it a shot.

Comment: You'll probably want `sendall`.  And, good point about closing the output pipe from p1, otherwise p2 won't finish...

Answer (score 2):

Yup the data is buffered in memory:

> "Note The data read is buffered in memory, so do not use this method
>   if the data size is large or unlimited." - [subprocess docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Unfortunately at the moment there is no way to asynchronously use Popen: [PEP3145](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3145/)

Rather than doing this all in python you can manually do

```
os.system("mysqldump -u uname -ppassword --add-drop-database --databases databaseName | gzip > fileName
```

")

with the appropriate string replacements using `string.format` of course; otherwise you're putting an unnecessary amount of stress on your computer, especially trying to communicate 200gb via a pipe ...

Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do? Right now it sounds like you're both dumping and zipping on the same computer.

---

Yes you can stream a file across the network .. I don't know if you want to directly stream the output of mysql directly though - you might want to look at your network capabilities before considering that

---

bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump -u uname -ppassword --add-drop-database --databases databaseName | gzip > fileName
 #transfer fileName to other computer
```

^ you can also put this in a crontab and have it run at intervals :)

Comment: Here's the situation:

Comment: I'm gathering data into a database on a system.  When the disk reaches a certain threshold I want to move a zipped dump to another system, and purge the db.  I think the best way to do this is dump/zip on the same machine.  I was trying to dream up a way of streaming the dump to the ultimate computer, but I can't think of a way to do this.  I had read that os.system is deprecated, so I thought I'd give subprocess a shot.  May as well us os.system though.  It's straight forward enough.  Thanks.

Comment: @glglgl it's not deprecated in glglgl ;D. also Zobal you might want to try a bash script rather than a python one. if these are on the same computer you don't need to use pipe's necessarily. those are for interprocess signalling more so then transferring giant quantities of data

Answer (score 2):

Your example code using two `subprocess.Popen` calls is correct (albeit slightly-improve-able), and this:

> ... I read that communicate caches the data in memory

is also correct—it reads into memory all of the standard-output and standard-error-output that the "communicating command" produces on a `subprocess.PIPE`—but *not a problem here*, because you have this:

```
p1 = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE)
P2 = Popen('gzip', stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=f)
p2.communicate()
```

You're calling `communicate()` on **`p2`**, whose stdout output is sent to `f` (an opened file), and whose stderr output—which is probably empty anyway (no errors occur)—is not being sent to a `PIPE`.  Thus, `p2.communicate()` would at worst have to read and buffer-up a grand total of zero bytes of stdout plus zero bytes of stderr.  It's actually a bit more clever, noticing that there is no `PIPE`, so it returns the tuple `(None, None)`.

If you were to call `p1.communicate()`, that would be more of an issue (although in this case you'd then be fighting with `p2`, the gzip process, for the output from `p1`, which would be even worse).  But you are not; `p1`'s output flows to `p2`, and `p2`'s output flows to a file.

Since none of `p2`'s output is sent to a `PIPE`, there is no need to call `p2.communicate()` here: you can simply call `p2.wait()`.  That makes it clearer that there's no data flowing back from `p2` (which I would say is a minor improvement to the code, although if you decide you want to capture `p2`'s stderr after all, you'd have to change that back).

---

Edit to add: as in glglgl's answer, it's important to close `p1`'s pipe to `p2` after creating p2, otherwise `p2` will wait for your Python process to send data to `p2`, too.