# How do you handle pipes and output in Python?

Tags: python, subprocess, avprobe

I'm attempting to execute this command within my python script:

```
avprobeCommand = "avprobe -of json -show_streams {0} | grep '\"duration\"' | sed -n 1p | sed 's/ //g'".format(hiOutput)
output = subprocess.check_output([avprobeCommand])
```

and I keep getting:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/Users/jmakaila/Documents/Development/Present/Web/video_dev/present-live-transcoder/Transcoder.py", line 60, in transcode
    output = subprocess.check_output([avprobeCommand])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1228, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I've already tried splitting the args up, but I keep getting an error for the -of json -show_streams part, which, for the record, looked like this:

```
subprocess.check_output(["avprobe", "-of json", "-show_streams", "{0}".format(hiOutput)
```

Comment: Alternative approaches are listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/295459/1858225 I recommend using the `pipes` module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pipes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the command as string, and pass `shell=True`:

```
import pipes
import subprocess

avprobeCommand = """avprobe -of json -show_streams {0} | grep '"duration"' | sed -n 1p | sed 's/ //g'""".format(pipes.quote(hiOutput))
output = subprocess.check_output(avprobeCommand, shell=True)
```

**UPDATE**: argument should be escaped using [`pipes.quote`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pipes.html#pipes.quote). (Use [`shlex.quote`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) if you use Python 3.3+).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, Thank you for comment. I updated the answer according to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you could move the post-processing into Python:

```
import json
from subprocess import check_output as qx

data = json.loads(qx(["avprobe", "-of", "json", "-show_streams", hiOutput]))
result = data["duration"]         # grep '"duration"'
             .partition("\n")[0]  # sed -n 1p
             .replace(" ", "")    # sed 's/ //g'
```

For a more general case, see [How do I use subprocess.Popen to connect multiple processes by pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295459/4279)