# Usage of stdout.close() in python's subprocess module when piping

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

In the python subprocess module, if we wanted to run the shell command

```
foo | grep bar
```

from within python, we might use

```
p1 = Popen(["foo"], stdout = PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", "bar"], stdin = p1.stdout, stdout = PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

I'm confused about the line `p1.stdout.close()`. If you'll forgive me, I'll trace through how I think the program works, and the error will hopefully reveal itself.

It seems to me that when the line `output = p2.communicate()[0]` is enacted by python, python tries to call `p2`, it recognizes that it needs output from `p1`. So it calls `p1`, which executes `foo` and throws the output on the stack so that `p2` can finish executing. And then `p2` finishes.

But nowhere in this trace does `p1.stdout.close()` actually happen. So what is actually happening? It seems to me that this ordering of lines might matter too, so that the following wouldn't work:

```
p1 = Popen(["foo"], stdout = PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()
p2 = Popen(["grep", "bar"], stdin = p1.stdout, stdout = PIPE)
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

And that's the status of my understanding.

Answer (score 8):

`p1.stdout.close()` is necessary for `foo` to detect when the pipe is broken e.g., when `p2` exits prematurely.

If there is no `p1.stdout.close()` then `p1.stdout` remains open in the parent process and even if `p2` exits; `p1` won't know that nobody reads `p1.stdout` i.e., `p1` will continue to write to `p1.stdout` until the corresponding OS pipe buffer is full and then it just blocks forever.

To emulate `foo | grep bar` shell command without a shell:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with Popen(['grep', 'bar'], stdin=PIPE) as grep, \
     Popen(['foo'], stdout=grep.stdin):
    grep.communicate()
```

See [How do I use subprocess.Popen to connect multiple processes by pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295459/4279)