# why is this linux command not working when executed using python?

Tags: python, unix, python-2.7, subprocess, mailx

I want to execute this linux command

"cat cflow_image.py | mailx -s "CFLOW Copy" foo@.foo.com". My requirement is to use this command in the python script.I am using subprocess module to achieve this.

Here is my piece of code for doing this,

```
def send_mail(mailid): 
   # This is mail the testbed info to the user
   mailid = args.mailID 
   print "* INFO file will be sent to your mailid *"
   subprocess.call("cat info.txt | mailx -s \"DEVSETUP\" {0}").format(mailid)
```

Following is the error when it is executed,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dev-installer.py", line 243, in <module>
    send_mail(args.mailID)
  File "dev-installer.py", line 204, in send_mail
    subprocess.call("cat info.txt | mailx -s \"DEVSETUP\" {0}").format(mailid)
  File "/sw/packages/python/2.7.4/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 524, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/sw/packages/python/2.7.4/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/sw/packages/python/2.7.4/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295459/how-do-i-use-subprocess-popen-to-connect-multiple-processes-by-pipes

Comment: Did you try to call subprocess with a list of arguments

Answer (score 3):

[`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) executes an executable. You are **not** passing a path to an executable as argument, you are passing a **shell** command line.

To execute a **shell** command you have to explicitly state that you want to execute the command in a shell by passing `shell=True` in the argument list.
Note that using `shell=True` with user-provided commands can be a securiy hazard.

Also note that when you are *not* using `shell=True` (e.g. when you don't specify it), you should pass a list of strings as argument which represent the already parsed argument list.
For example:

```
subprocess.call('ls -l')
```

Will try to execute a command named `ls -l` and will probably fail if you don't have an executable with that name in the `PATH`, while:

```
subprocess.call(['ls', '-l'])
```

will call the `ls` executable with the argument `-l`.

If you don't want to manually write such lists use `shlex.split` to parse the "command line":

```
subprocess.call(shlex.split('executable arg1 arg2 --option1 --option2 "string argument"'))
```

Will result in the call:

```
subprocess.call(['executable', 'arg1', 'arg2', '--option1', '--option2', 'string argument'])
```

Note how the quotes were properly handled (however no shell expansion is performed!)

Comment: Worth noting: be careful with using `shell=True` if an outside user can, in any way, alter the command issued to `subprocess.call()`

Comment: @OozeMeister That's what I meant by "using `shell=True` with user-provided commands can be a securiy hazard."

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a shell command, so Python should invoke a shell which would parse and run your command. But you're telling Python to invoke a command whose name is `cat info.txt | mailx -s "DEVSETUP" foo@.foo.com`, i.e. there should be an executable by that name on the command search path — and no such command exists.

`subprocess.call` supports all keyword arguments of the [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) constructor. You can pass the keyword argument `shell=True` to indicate that what you have is some shell code and not the name of an executable file.

```
subprocess.call("cat info.txt | mailx -s \"DEVSETUP\" {0}".format(mailid),
                shell=True)
```

However, beware that the value of `mailid` will be interpolated in the shell snippet, which will break if it contains shell special characters, as in `bob@example.com (Bob Smith)` or `Bob Smith <bob@example.com>`. You should arrange to quote any special character that is present in `mailid`.

Another problem with the command you posted is that if any error occurs while reading `info.txt`, it won't be detected. You can remedy that by avoiding the useless use of `cat`:

```
subprocess.call("<info.txt mailx -s \"DEVSETUP\" {0}".format(mailid),
                shell=True)
```

Given that the command is simple, you don't need to invoke a shell at all. If no shell gets involved, you don't need to worry about quoting. You can easily make Python open the `info.txt` file for reading.

```
body_file = open("info.txt")
status = subprocess.call(["mailx", "-s", "DEVSETUP", mailid], stdin=body_file)
body_file.close()
if status != 0:
    … handle mailx failure …
```