# subprocess child traceback

Tags: python, subprocess, traceback

I want to access the traceback of a python programm running in a subprocess.

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#exceptions) says:

> Exceptions raised in the child process, before the new program has started to execute, will be re-raised in the parent. Additionally, the exception object will have one extra attribute called child_traceback, which is a string containing traceback information from the child’s point of view.

Contents of `my_sub_program.py`:

```
raise Exception("I am raised!")
```

Contents of `my_main_program.py`:

```
import sys
import subprocess
try:
    subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, "my_sub_program.py"])
except Exception as e:
    print e.child_traceback
```

If I run `my_main_program.py`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_main_program.py", line 6, in <module>
    print e.child_traceback
AttributeError: 'CalledProcessError' object has no attribute 'child_traceback'
```

How can I access the traceback of the subprocess without modifying the subprocess program code? This means, I want to avoid adding a large `try/except` clause around my whole sub-program code, but rather handle error logging from my main program.

**Edit:** `sys.executable` should be replaceable with an interpreter differing from the one running the main program.

Comment: Doc says "before the new program has started to execute", in your case the exception was raised while the new program was executed, hence no `child_traceback`. Once the new program is running you need to catch the `CalledProcessError` exception and do as the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849998/how-to-catch-exception-output-from-python-subprocess-check-output using `CalledProcessError.output`

Comment: In my example, `CalledProcessError.output` did only capture the standard output, but not the traceback of the Exception.

Comment: This is probably because output is sent on `stderr`. Look at answers from the question I sent you the link above for more details

Answer (score 0):

As you're starting another Python process, you can also try to use the `multiprocessing` Python module ; by sub-classing the `Process` class it is quite easy to get exceptions from the target function:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import traceback
import functools

class MyProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Process.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._pconn, self._cconn = Pipe()
        self._exception = None

    def run(self):
        try:
            Process.run(self)
            self._cconn.send(None)
        except Exception as e:
            tb = traceback.format_exc()
            self._cconn.send((e, tb))
            # raise e  # You can still rise this exception if you need to

    @property
    def exception(self):
        if self._pconn.poll():
            self._exception = self._pconn.recv()
        return self._exception


p = MyProcess(target=functools.partial(execfile, "my_sub_program.py"))
p.start()
p.join() #wait for sub-process to end

if p.exception:
    error, traceback = p.exception
    print 'you got', traceback
```

The trick is to have the target function executing the Python sub-program, this is done by using `functools.partial`.

Comment: Does this solution allow the subprocess to run in a different interpreter than the main program? As I see your suggestion I notice that it was misleading to use `sys.executable` in my example. However, in the context of my question, I need to start scripts in another virtual environment than the main process. (the main process will be some kind of scheduler)

Comment: Actually `multiprocessing` does `os.fork` on POSIX platforms, so it's not a new virtual environment ; however you can limit the amount of shared data between processes by starting the `Process` objects early, this is maybe fair enough for your needs

Comment: If you're doing a kind of scheduler why not using something like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)