# Python subprocess module: Catch exception from a child process in parent process

Tags: python, exception, process, subprocess

How to catch exception from a child process in the parent process. The child process is created using Python's subprocess.Popen() like so:

division_by_zero.py

```
print(1/0)
```

parent.py

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['python', 'division_by_zero.py'])
```

The child process raises an exception

> ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

. How to catch that in parent process?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Multiprocessing: Handling Child Errors in Parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924104/python-multiprocessing-handling-child-errors-in-parent)

Comment: Check this answer [How to catch exception output from Python subprocess.check_output()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849998/how-to-catch-exception-output-from-python-subprocess-check-output)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to directly "catch" that exception. But I have only started researching this myself.

You could use pipes for a similar result, like so:

in `parent.py`

```
import subprocess 

process = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'division_by_zero.py'], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
errorText = stderr.decode()
if 'ZeroDivisionError' in errorText:
    print('Zero divison error encountered while executing subprocess')
```

in `division_by_zero.py`

```
print(0/1)
```

The trick is that we redirect all error output to a pipeline between our process and the subprocess. Normal output can also be captured in a similar fashion by passing `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` to `.Popen()` function.

Inspired by this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35633457/13459588