# Catching error from subprocess.Popen() when executable fails

Tags: python, error-handling, subprocess

Could anyone recommend some improvements to the following script such that if the Application.exe file fails, the script ends rather than just becoming hanging indefinitely?

```
application = r'.\Application.exe'
input_params = '-i Input_1 -j Input_2

process = (application,input_params)
p = subprocess.Popen(" ".join(process),shell= True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()
```

When the application file failed there was no exception thrown, is it possible to have subprocess throw one in such an event?

---

Edit: Implemented the p.returncode statement.

To revise my original question, when the Application.exe program fails it displays the following window

[image]

It is only after I close this window does the program proceed (eg: p.returncode will return the value 255).

Is there a way to either have this window not be displayed or automatically closed or have the program proceed despite having this window displayed?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to catch exception output from Python subprocess.check_output()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849998/how-to-catch-exception-output-from-python-subprocess-check-output)

```
try:
    subprocess.check_output(...)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print e.output
```

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(['bitcoin', 'sendtoaddress', ..], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output, error = p.communicate()
if p.returncode != 0: 
   print("bitcoin failed %d %s %s" % (p.returncode, output, error))
```

Comment: Thanks for the link! I implemented the changes and will need to make some changes to my original post.