# Why subprocess.check_output not working when running as service

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to make python scrapy that use flask running in vps server.
Python scrapy runs well when use following command.

```
python3 scraper_app.py
```

That works well and I got the desired result.
But if i close the ssh(putty), the command is closed with that.
So I'm trying to run command as service.
I've done all needed to run as service.
And

```
systemctl start scrapy.service
```

This command works well, but while running following error occurs.

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['scrapy', 'crawl', 'bcpa', '-a', 'file=uploads/broward_err.csv']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
```

The related code is as follows.

```
subprocess.check_output(['scrapy', 'crawl', spider_name, '-a', f'file={filename}'])
```

Why this happens although that works well when runs as shell?
Please help me.

here is the error log(journalctl -u xxx.service)

```
Nov 17 10:17:09 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:  * Serving Flask app "scraper_app" (lazy loading)
Nov 17 10:17:09 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:  * Environment: production
Nov 17 10:17:09 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
Nov 17 10:17:09 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:    Use a production WSGI server instead.
Nov 17 10:17:09 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:  * Debug mode: on
Nov 17 10:17:09 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:  * Running on http://216.158.230.201:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Nov 17 10:17:09 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:  * Restarting with stat
Nov 17 10:17:09 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:  * Debugger is active!
Nov 17 10:17:09 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:  * Debugger PIN: 446-889-261
Nov 17 10:17:13 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]: 3.83.20.243 - - [17/Nov/2019 10:17:13] "GET /upload HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Nov 17 10:17:22 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]: 3.83.20.243 - - [17/Nov/2019 10:17:22] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 302 -
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]: 3.83.20.243 - - [17/Nov/2019 10:17:23] "GET /run?file=uploads%2Fbroward_err.csv&spider=bcpa&county=broward&sunbiz_address= HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:     response = self.handle_exception(e)
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:     raise value
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:     raise value
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:   File "/root/LLC-lookup-scrapy/scraper_app.py", line 132, in run_spider
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:     subprocess.check_output(['scrapy', 'crawl', spider_name, '-a', f'file={filename}'])
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 356, in check_output
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:     **kwargs).stdout
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 438, in run
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]:     output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
Nov 17 10:17:23 ubuntu18.is.cc env[9486]: subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['scrapy', 'crawl', 'bcpa', '-a', 'file=uploads/broward_err.csv']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
```

Comment: You'll probably need to capture the output of the `scrapy crawl...` command to figure out what's going. Possibly if you look at the logs for your service (`journalctl -u scrapy.service`) you'll see something.

Comment: I've attached log from ```journalctl -u xxx.service)```.

Comment: @JingzhunLi: That’s not output from `scrapy` itself, though, but from your script that was already reporting the error.

Comment: @DavisHerring, so what's your opinion?

Comment: @JingzhunLi: Uh… that you should provide more information about the process that “actually” failed if you want an answer?

Comment: yes, i also want to see the result from scrapy spider, but i don't know how to get the log from scrapy spider function call. if you know, plz tell me the way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24850026/939364

Comment: in script, i use both `print(e.output)` and `logging.info(e.output)`, but I can't find the log string. Only main message python leaves is logged and other output string is not logged. Where can i find the entire log that i leave in my script?