# Python subprocess correct exceptoion handling

Tags: python, subprocess

I have class for decrypting passwords like below:

```
class Decrypt:
    def __init__(self, password):
    self.password = password

    def decrypt_file(self):
        command = "perl -e \'require \"Utilities.pm\";  print my $pass = Utilities::Decrypt(\"E\", \"{}\")\';".format(self.password)
        process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        output, error = process.communicate()
        return output
```

Would anybody help me with how correct exception handling for subprocess look like in this case?

Comment: What sort of exception are you trying to deal with?

Comment: @TookieWookie I would need something general, catching stderr might be fine

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849998/how-to-catch-exception-output-from-python-subprocess-check-output