# Check Security Group existence in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, aws-cli, aws-security-group

I use aws-cli v1 and I want to check the SG existence is certain VPC.

I use the command `describe-security-groups` which seems to be the only available for this task:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --region=us-east-2 --output=json --group-name=test
```

The problem is that when the group is non-existent it throws unhandleable error in shell

> An error occurred (InvalidGroup.NotFound) when calling the DescribeSecurityGroups operation: The security group 'test' does not exist in default VPC 'vpc-xxxxxxxx'

which results in the following error in Python function:

> File "script.py", line 93, in makesg
> ap = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
> **kwargs).stdout
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
> output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
> subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['aws', 'ec2', 'describe-security-groups', '--region=eu-east-1', '--vpc-id=vpc-xxxxxxx', '--group-name=test']' returned non-zero exit status 255.

Is there any aws-cli command that allows checking existence? I found only [security-group-exists](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/wait/security-group-exists.html), however it is a sub-command of [wait](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/wait/) and is not applicable standalone.

Catching `subprocess.CalledProcessError` error in the function doesn't seem very Pythonic for me, what is the best practice?

Comment: Are you open to use the Python AWS SDK or you have reasons to stick with calling the AWS CLI from Python?

Comment: Yep, I'd rather stick to aws cli due to existing codebase, however if you have beautiful solution in AWS SDK, you are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of querying the specific SG and handling the exception, you could instead query all Security Groups with AWS CLI, get the result and handle the comparison in Python:

```py
security_group_names_str = subprocess.check_output(['aws', 'ec2', 'describe-security-groups', '--output=json', '--query=SecurityGroups[].GroupName'])
security_group_names = json.loads(security_group_names_str)

if SG_NAME_TO_FIND in security_group_names:
  handle_sg_found()
else:
  handle_sg_not_found()
```

As mentioned already in the other answer, you could implement the same also with [`boto3`](http://boto3.amazonaws.com) (AWS SDK).

Answer (score 0):

> Catching subprocess.CalledProcessError error in the function doesn't seem very Pythonic for me, what is the best practice?

It is pythonic, you can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849998/how-to-catch-exception-output-from-python-subprocess-check-output) to handle the different error cases. Something along the lines of

```
try:
    subprocess.checkout_ouput(...)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exception:
    if security_group_not_found(exception):
         handle_it()
    else:
        raise exception
```

Would be a clean way to handle it. you can also look at the [aws sdk](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/) it might handle your use-case better.