# Return full error message from subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I would like to get a full, descriptive error message from failed Python script executed with subprocess module.

I have a following script `sub_script.py` which fails and produces `IndexError: pop from empty list` error when executed on it's own:

```py
# sub_script.py

empty_list = []
empty_list.pop()
```

I am calling `sub_script.py` from `sub_test.py` as follows:

```py
# sub_test.py

import subprocess
import sys

print(str(subprocess.run([sys.executable, 'sub_script.py'],
                         check=True,
                         capture_output=True)))
```

However I am only getting `subprocess.CalledProcessError` error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/my_user/Desktop/my_dir/sub_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(str(subprocess.run([sys.executable, 'sub_script.py'],
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 528, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9', 'sub_script.py']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I would like to see a full description of the error returned from `sub_script.py` (`IndexError: pop from empty list`) when it's executed with a subprocess in `sub_test.py`.

Is it possible to get full error when script executes and fails within `subprocess.run`?

Comment: This answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849998/how-to-catch-exception-output-from-python-subprocess-check-output/24850026

Comment: I tried it already, it still returns `subprocess.CalledProcessError` instead of `IndexError: pop from empty list`

Comment: Have you tried capturing `stdout` and `stderr` from `subprocess.run()`?

Comment: If you want to actually have an IndexException, you'll have to import the file and do it through python not subprocess, if you just want the output of the error, the link should work.

Comment: I have to use subprocess, I cannot import file @T.Kelher

Comment: @MattDMo Yes, the output is the same as with `capture_output=True`

Comment: if I run 'subprocess.run([sys.executable, 'test.py'], check=True, capture_output=True)', and catch the exception with ' except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:' I get "b'Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File "C:\\Users\\Gebruiker\\Documents\\test\\test.py", line 2, in <module>\r\n    output[50]\r\nIndexError: list index out of range\r\n'" when I print(e.stderr). But that output is not enough you want to do try, and actually except the indexerror instead of subprocess.CalledProcessError?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the return value of the `subprocess.run` call instead of immediately converting it to a `str`, and do not have `check=True`.

```py
# main.py
import subprocess
import sys

command = [sys.executable, 'task.py']
outcome = subprocess.run(command, check=False, capture_output=True)
print(f"returncode = {outcome.returncode}")
if outcome.returncode != 0:
    # there was an error, we assume the traceback was printed to stderr
    print("there was an error :\n")
    print(outcome.stderr.decode("utf-8"))
```

```py
# task.py
empty_list = []
empty_list.pop()
```

output :

```
returncode = 1
there was an error :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "task.py", line 2, in <module>
    empty_list.pop()
IndexError: pop from empty list
```