# Using subprocess to get output of grep piped through head -1

Tags: python, grep, pipe, subprocess, head

The gist of what I'm trying to do is this:

```
grep -n "some phrase" {some file path} | head -1
```

I would like to pass the output of this into python. What I've tried so far is:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('grep -n "some phrase" {some file path} | head -1',shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I get back a lot of messages saying

```
"grep: writing output: Broken pipe"
```

I'm not very familiar with the `subprocess` module, I would like advice as to how to get this output, and what I am currently doing wrong.

Comment: It works for me on linux.

Comment: found similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295459/how-do-i-use-subprocess-popen-to-connect-multiple-processes-by-pipes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docs show you how to [replace shell piping](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) using Popen:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen


p1 = Popen(['grep', '-n', 'some phrase', '{some file path}'],stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(['head', '-1'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
out,err = output = p2.communicate()
```

Comment: @user3467349, he/she seems to want to get the line  number that  some phrase is on which is what out should return. Either way you need to pass the output of process 1 to the input of process 2 to replicate the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks so much. So if I would have to pipe it through multiple things in the shell, I could create a new Popen for each of those.

Comment: Yes exactly. All it is doing basically is sending the output of one process into the input of another.

Answer (score 1):

Let shell do it for you (lazy workaround):

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['-c', 'grep -n "some phrase" {some file path} | head -1'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print out, err
```