# Getting an error in Python when trying to use stdin: io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to std in an xml file.  I read the xml file from subversion, updated a line in the file and now I am trying to create a jenkins job by using subporcess.Popen and stdin

```
test = subprocess.Popen('svn cat http://localhost/svn/WernerTest/JenkinsJobTemplates/trunk/smartTemplate.xml --username admin --password admin', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
job = test.stdout.read().replace("@url@", "http://localhost/svn/WernerTest/TMS/branches/test1")
output = io.StringIO()
output.write(job)
subprocess.Popen('java -jar D:\\applications\\Jenkins\\war\\WEB-INF\\jenkins-cli.jar\\jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ create-job test7', stdin=output)
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "D:\scripts\jenkinsGetJobs.py", line 20, in <module>
subprocess.Popen('java -jar D:\\applications\\Jenkins\\war\\WEB-INF\\jenkins-cli.jar\\jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ create-job test7', stdin=output)
File "D:\applications\Python 3.5\lib\subprocess.py", line 914, 
in __init__errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
File "D:\applications\Python 3.5\lib\subprocess.py", line 1127, in _get_handles
p2cread = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(stdin.fileno())
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

So how do I pass in the updated file to the next subprocess?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a pipe and write the data directly to that pipe:

```
test = subprocess.Popen(
    'svn cat http://localhost/svn/WernerTest/JenkinsJobTemplates/trunk/smartTemplate.xml --username admin --password admin',
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
job = test.stdout.read().replace("@url@", "http://localhost/svn/WernerTest/TMS/branches/test1")

jenkins = subprocess.Popen(
    'java -jar D:\\applications\\Jenkins\\war\\WEB-INF\\jenkins-cli.jar\\jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ create-job test7',
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
jenkins.communicate(job)
```

The [`Popen.communicate()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) takes the first argument and sends that as stdin to the subprocess.

Note that I set the [`universal_newlines` argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) to `True` for Jenkins as well; the alternative would be for you to explicitly encode the `job` string to a suitable codec that Jenkins will accept.

Comment: I am getting the following for an error now:  TypeError:  Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

Comment: @Dan: oops, I missed your `universal_newlines` argument there; you probably need to use the same on the Jenkins process for it to accept `str` as input, or you'll need to explicitly encode your data manually.

Comment: By using stdin=subprocess.PIPE, is this call actually getting the correct data from the line test.stdout.read().replace.....?

Comment: @Dan: the process will get whatever you pass in as a first argument to the `Popen.communicate()` call.

Comment: Sorry, thanks.  I am getting an unable to access jar error but that should hopefully be something else now.  Thanks for the help Martijn!

Answer (score 3):

`Popen()` accepts only real files (valid `.fileno()` at least).
[@Martijn Pieters♦' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30171588/4279) shows how pass the data if you can load it all at once in memory (also, `jenkins` process is not started until `svn` produces *all* output).

Here's how to read one line at a time (svn and jenkins processes run in parallel):

```
#!/usr/bine/env python3
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with Popen(svn_cmd, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as svn, \
     Popen(java_cmd, stdin=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as java:
    for line in svn.stdout:
        line = line.replace('@url@', 'http://localhost/svn/WernerTest/TMS/branches/test1')
        java.stdin.write(line)
if java.returncode != 0:
   "handle error"
```

see `svn_cmd`, `java_cmd` definitions below (you don't need `shlex.split(cmd)` on Windows -- note: no `shell=True`).

---

If you didn't need to replace `@url@` then It would look like you are trying to emulate: `svn_cmd | java_cmd` pipeline, where:

```
svn_cmd = 'svn cat http://localhost/svn/WernerTest/JenkinsJobTemplates/trunk/smartTemplate.xml --username admin --password admin'
java_cmd = 'java -jar D:\\applications\\Jenkins\\war\\WEB-INF\\jenkins-cli.jar\\jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ create-job test7'
```

The simplest way is to envoke the shell:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(svn_cmd + ' | ' + java_cmd, shell=True)
```

You could emulate it in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

#NOTE: use a list for compatibility with POSIX systems
with Popen(java_cmd.split(), stdin=PIPE) as java, \
     Popen(svn_cmd.split(), stdout=java.stdin):
    java.stdin.close() # close unused pipe in the parent
    # no more code here (the for-loop is inside an OS code that implements pipes)
if java.returncode != 0:
   "handle error here"
```

See [How do I use subprocess.Popen to connect multiple processes by pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295459/4279)

Comment: The *If you wouldn't need to replace `@url@`* bit is *crucial* though. It is why I didn't just dupe the post to the one you linked to.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yes. I've missed it at first. I've updated the answer to include the 'replace' step.