# subprocess call to setup crontab

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi, subprocess

I'm trying to use a subprocess call in python to add a cron job entry:

```
from subprocess import call

call(["(crontab -l; echo '* * * * * ls -l | tee tresults.txt') | sort - | uniq - | crontab - "])
```

And I don't know what I'm doing wrong! This is the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subprocess.call()` does not run the shell (`/bin/sh`) by default.

You either need to [emulate multiple pipes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295459/4279) or just pass `shell=True`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import check_call

check_call("(crontab -l; echo '* * * * * ls -l | tee tresults.txt') | "
           "sort - | uniq - | crontab - ",
           shell=True)
```

Comment: what if the check_call is running some long-running python external program. How would you end it immediately if desired?

Comment: It seems completely unrelated to the current question. If you have a new question; [post it as a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you're having the problem here is that the `call` function from `subprocess` has two ways to be called (referencing the Python 2.7 docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

1. If you use `call` with a single string as an argument, you need to also pass 'shell=True':

   ```
   call("a long command with many arguments", shell=True)
   ```
2. If you don't want to call `shell=True`, which can be bad in some cases, you need to append each argument in it's own string, like shown in the Python docs example: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module

   ```
   call(["ls", "-l"])
   ```

In your case, I'd try adding a `shell=True` argument to your `call` call and see if that helps.