# Chained popen processes not getting output

Tags: python, sorting, subprocess

I've been trying to sort some very large CSVs using the command line sort, so that they are ready for processing in Python. I'm trying to use subprocess to just do this in Python, but can't get it to work. Here's the code:

```
import subprocess
fn = 'path/to/filename'
p1 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('tail -n +2 {}'.format(fn)), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("sort -t$'\t' -k2,2n -k3,3"), stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = p2.communicate()[0]
print(output)
```

When I print

```
p1.communicate()[0]
```

I get the bytestream of the file, as expected, but when I print

```
p2.communicate()[0]
```

I get an empty bytestream, and I can't figure out why.

As a side note, if there's a better way of sorting a CSV too large to fit in memory, then I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: unrelated: to make the shell pipeline more readable in Python, you could [use `plumbum`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16709666/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extraneous dollar sign in the `-t` flag of your sort command, remove it and it should work:

```
p2 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("sort -t'\t' -k2,2n -k3,3"), stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: @Jeremy: removing `$` works by accident (because Python and /bin/sh interpret `\t` in the same way). In general, `$'...'` is interpreted by `/bin/sh` and you can't just drop it blindly; you should consider what it does in each case.