# How can I construct a subprocess call in Python for 2 or more commands for OS X or Linux?

Tags: python, subprocess

I would like to perform within a Python script the following:
more 20151010_ABC.txt | grep QST > 20151010_ABC.txt.QST

for a number (almost a 1000 files) of such files.

Then,

to open within the script the VIM editor, passing on demand either *.txt or *.QST or NONE files as above.

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Sample:

```
import subprocess
more = subprocess.Popen(['more', '20151010_AlterAeon.txt.prsd'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
grep = subprocess.Popen(['grep', 'LVL'], stdin=more.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
feed = subprocess.Popen(['>', '20151010_AlterAeon.txt.prsd.LVL'], stdin=grep.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
end_of_pipe = feed.stdout
#print "Files:", end_of_pipe
for line in end_of_pipe:
    print line.strip()
```

Comment: Thank you @J.F.Sebastian  for your guidance, as probably understood being a newbie here!

Comment: Why would you ever run `more` in a pipeline?

Comment: related: [How do I use subprocess.Popen to connect multiple processes by pipes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/295459/4279)

Comment: is there a reason to use external processes here? You could emulate the pipeline in pure Python: `for line in file: if 'LVL' in line: output_file.write(line)`

Comment: Thank you @J.F.Sebastian for the related comment.  That solved (in a way) my question in a simple way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question solved mainly based on the following:

```
result = subprocess.Popen('more 20151010_AlterAeon.txt.prsd | grep LVL >  
20151010_AlterAeon.txt.prsd.LVL',  
stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
```