# Python subprocess: chaining commands with subprocess.run

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, python-3.5

I'm experimenting with [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) in Python 3.5. To chain two commands together, I would have thought that the following should work:

```
import subprocess

ps1 = subprocess.run(['ls'], universal_newlines=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
ps2 = subprocess.run(['cowsay'], stdin=ps1.stdout)
```

However, this fails with:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

`ps2` was expecting a file-like object, but the output of `ps1` is a simple string.

Is there a way to chain commands together with `subprocess.run`?

Answer (score 6):

`subprocess.run()` can't be used to implement `ls | cowsay` without the shell because it doesn't allow to run the individual commands concurrently: each `subprocess.run()` call waits for the process to finish that is why it returns `CompletedProcess` object (notice the word "completed" there). `ps1.stdout` in your code is a string that is why you have to pass it as `input` and not the `stdin` parameter that expects a file/pipe (valid `.fileno()`).

Either use the shell:

```
subprocess.run('ls | cowsay', shell=True)
```

Or use `subprocess.Popen`, to run the child processes concurrently:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cowsay = Popen('cowsay', stdin=PIPE)
ls = Popen('ls', stdout=cowsay.stdin)
cowsay.communicate()
ls.wait()
```

See [How do I use subprocess.Popen to connect multiple processes by pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295459/4279)

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of the Popen syntax but was specifically looking for how to chain commands with `subprocess.run` in Python 3.5+. And it is indeed possible to chain commands using the `input` argument to `subprocess.run`.

Comment: @ChrisClark: do you understand the difference between: `ls | cowsay` and `output=$(ls); cowsay  <<< "$output"`?

Answer (score 5):

Turns out that `subprocess.run` has an `input` argument to handle this:

```
ps1 = subprocess.run(['ls'], universal_newlines=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
ps2 = subprocess.run(['cowsay'], universal_newlines=True, input=ps1.stdout)
```

Also, the following works as well, which doesn't use `input`:

```
ps1 = subprocess.run(['ls'], universal_newlines=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
ps2 = subprocess.run(['cowsay', ps1.stdout], universal_newlines=True)
```