# subprocess popen to run commands (HDFS/hadoop)

Tags: python, hadoop, subprocess, popen

I am trying to use `subprocess.popen` to run commands on my machine.

This is what I have so far

```
cmdvec = ['/usr/bin/hdfs', 'dfs', '-text', '/data/ds_abc/clickstream/{d_20151221-2300}/*', '|', 'wc', '-l']

subproc = subprocess.Popen(cmdvec, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=None, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

If I run the command in my terminal I get an output of

```
15/12/21 16:09:31 INFO lzo.GPLNativeCodeLoader: Loaded native gpl library
15/12/21 16:09:31 INFO lzo.LzoCodec: Successfully loaded & initialized native-lzo library [hadoop-lzo rev 9cd4009fb896ac12418449e4678e16eaaa3d5e0a]
15/12/21 16:09:31 INFO compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor [.snappy]
15305
```

The number `15305` is the desired value I want.

When I run the command by splitting it and converting it into a list, I do this to try to get the lines:

```
for i in subproc.stdout:
    print(i)
```

However this gives me the data as if this command was ran because all the data from the file is being displayed.

`/usr/bin/hdfs dfs -text /data/ds_abc/clickstream/{d_20151221-2300}/*`

It doesn't seem like the pipe `|` has been used to count the number of lines are in all the files

Comment: related: [How do I use subprocess.Popen to connect multiple processes by pipes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/295459/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, passing the pipe `|` character as an argument to `subprocess.Popen` does not create a pipeline of processes the same way that it would in something like Bash.  Instead, the pipe `|` character is being passed an argument to a single process.

Instead, you would need to chain together 2 separate `subprocess.Popen` calls to simulate a Bash-style pipeline.  This documentation on the `subprocess` module contains more details.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline