# Error using shlex and subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, shlex

Hi I am trying to run this command in python's subprocess with shlex split, however, I haven't found anything helpful for this particular case :

```
ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | grep -v 192.* | awk '{print $2}'
```

I get an with ifconfig error because the split with the single and double quotes and even the white space before the $ sign are not correct.
Please Help.

Comment: The `grep` commands are a bit off, `.` is a wildcard, and `*` isn't, and `*` is a shell wildcard, so you want to escape it in the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `shell=True` (shell will interpret `|`) and triple quote string literal (otherwise you need to escape `"`, `'` inside the string literal):

```
import subprocess
cmd = r"""ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -v 127\.0\.0\.1 | grep -v 192\. | awk '{print $2}'"""
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

or you can do it in harder way ([**Replacing shell pipeline** from `subprocess` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline)):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, call                                       

p1 = Popen(['ifconfig'], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(['grep', 'inet '], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p3 = Popen(['grep', '-v', r'127\.0\.0\.1'], stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p4 = Popen(['grep', '-v', r'192\.'], stdin=p3.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
call(['awk', '{print $2}'], stdin=p4.stdout)
```

Comment: 1- `.close()` calls are missing in the second code example. 2- It is better to [invert the order if you want to emulate the pipeline by hand (you don't need `.close()` calls in this case)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9164238/4279).