# Popen piping 2 cmd hanging and not giving expected result

Tags: python, linux, grep, subprocess

I am trying to use grep and pipe it to uniq to get unique results...(greping for ip addresses here)

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['grep','-sRIEho', '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}', '/tmp/test'])
p2 = subprocess.Popen(['uniq'],stdin=process.stdout)    
stdout,stderr = p2.communicate()
```

The problem is that this hangs and doesn't show me unique results...
Here's the '/tmp/test' file:

```
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
1.9.12.12
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
```

And the result well... It's the same
Any idea what's happening here?
Btw I cannot use Shell=True here (user supplied filename)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.communicate()` returns `None` unless you pass `PIPE` i.e., both `stdout`, `stderr` are always `None` in your example. Also, you should close `process.stdout` in the parent so that `grep` would know if `uniq` dies prematurely. It doesn't explain why `grep` "hangs". The issue might be `grep` args such as `-R` (recursive, follows symlinks).

Try working solutions from [How do I use subprocess.Popen to connect multiple processes by pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295459/4279) e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with Popen(['uniq'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE) as uniq, \
     Popen(['grep'] + grep_args, stdout=uniq.stdin):
    output = uniq.communicate()[0]
```

Or:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from plumbum.cmd import grep, uniq  # $ pip install plumbum

output_text = (grep[grep_args] | uniq)()
```