# How to get the latest result from an adb logical grep search from python?

Tags: python, subprocess, adb, logcat, android-logcat

I already have an android emulator instance open in the background. I want to write a python script that can use subprocess module to grep the logcat for a certain word, and return the latest (based on timestamp) result from that search as a string. How to do this?

```
adb logcat | grep keyword
>> 00:00:01 keyword
>> 00:00:02 keyword
>> 00:00:03 keyword
```

want python script that will return the line "00:00:03 keyword"

```
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['adb', 'logcat', '| grep keyword'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    last_result=read_last_result(proc)
```

Comment: Have you tried the [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module? There is also a "[Regular Expressions HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)" on the official Python site which you might find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To get the last line from subprocess' stdout:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from collections import deque
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with Popen('adb -d logcat <filter-spec>'.split(), stdout=PIPE) as adb:
    last_line = deque(adb.stdout, maxlen=1).pop() # get last line
```

See [`adb logcat` options](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html).

If you want to emulate the `'adb logcat | grep keyword'` shell command literally, see [How do I use subprocess.Popen to connect multiple processes by pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295459/4279)