# convert from bash shell to python3 using subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess, popen

I'm struggling with converting from bash shell to python3.

Here's shell command that I want to convert to python:

> ```
> cat $outDir/aDir/* | cut -f2 | sort -u > $outDir/outFile.txt
> ```

I already use `subprocess.call()`and it worked but I want to know how make it with Popen().

Here's my code which didn't work :

```
import subprocess
import glob

filePath = outDir + 'aDir/*'
outFilePath = outDir + '/outFile.txt'

fileList = []
for files in glob.glob(filePath):
    fileList.append(files)
with open(files, 'r') as inFile, open(outFilePath, 'w') as outFile : 
  p = subprocess.Popen(['cat'], stdin=inFile, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)   
  p2 = subprocess.Popen(['cut', '-f2'], stdin = p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  p3 = subprocess.Popen(['sort', '-u'], stdin = p2.stdout, stdout = outFile)
```

and could you explain why `shell=True` is harmful? I saw it in many answers but don't know why...

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess explains why you want to avoid `shell=True`.

Comment: @tripleee: and [this shows that `shell=True` can be useful](http://stackoverflow.com/q/295459/4279) (if there is no untrusted input then it is more likely that one makes a mistake while reimplementing the shell pipeline using `subprocess.Popen` directly than one gets an error due to incompatibilities for a simple shell command).

Comment: The problem in't that it is useless, but that using it requires understanding. The shell has the unfortunate honor of having proportionally more users who don't know even the absolute basics than even PHP and VBscript combined. (This question is markedly above average in that respect.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a list of files to `cat`
So

```
subprocess.Popen(['cat'], stdin=inFile, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

should become

```
subprocess.Popen(['cat'] + [fileList], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

And consequently `inFile` should no longer be needed

So, all in all

```
import subprocess
import glob

filePath = outDir + '/aDir/*'
outFilePath = outDir + '/outFile.txt'

fileList = glob.glob(filePath)
with open(outFilePath, 'w') as outFile: 
  subprocess.Popen(['cat'] + [fileList], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  p2 = subprocess.Popen(['cut', '-f2'], stdin = p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  p3 = subprocess.Popen(['sort', '-u'], stdin = p2.stdout, stdout = outFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about just using `shell=True` and keeping the pipes?

```
with open(files, 'r') as inFile, open(outFilePath, 'w') as outFile : 
  p = subprocess.Popen('cut -f2 | sort -u', shell=True, stdin=filePath, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  p.communicate()
```

Or even, more simply:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("cat {} | cut -f2 | sort -u > '{}'".format(filePath, outFilePath), shell=True)
p.communicate()
```

Or, even *more* simply (thanks [@tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee)!):

```
subprocess.call("cat {} | cut -f2 | sort -u > '{}'".format(filePath, outFilePath), shell=True)
```

As for `shell=True`, the only danger is really if your input is not safe. I'd recommend quoting all inputs with single quotes, and escaping and sanitizing all inputs.

Comment: If `in` contains funky stuff, you need to perform additional steps to escape it from shell interpretation.

Comment: `open(files, 'r')` simply throws an error if `files` is a list.

Comment: And once you've fixed those things, `subprocess.Popen` is just inconvenient; use `subprocess.call` instead.

Comment: Sorry, `in` was meant to be `filePath` per OP's example. Also added `call()`, great point, thanks!