# How to call combined linux commands on python subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I write this command on linux

```
netstat -ant | wc -l
```

but when I try to call from python with

```
subprocess.Popen(['netstat','-ant','|','wc','-l'])
```

I cant get all output, I see just result of first command (netstat -ant).
How can I process this command on python ? (note: this command gives a int as a result)

Comment: *Show your code.* Don't make us guess what you've written.

Comment: Why do you need `grep` and `wc` external programs anyway?  Its not that difficult to do these operations in Python.

Comment: Maybe this previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295459/how-do-i-use-subprocess-popen-to-connect-multiple-processes-by-pipes) can help you.

Comment: you're right. I looked and found answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there's any easier method but you can go like:

```
from subprocess import run, Popen, PIPE
sess1 = run(['netstat', 'ant'], stdout=PIPE)
sess2 = Popen(['grep', '"SYN"'], stdin=PIPE)
sess2.stdin.write(sess1.stdout)
sess2.communicate() # required?
```

Comment: thanks, I found a solution like this