# How to execute a shell command in Python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, shell

[image: Written both shell and oython codes for understanding]

Please help to achieve output of shell in python

Comment: typo error in above python code line 5. It is hpeesofde.exe instead of xwgen.exe

Comment: Please delete that image and paste your two console I/O blocks in as text. A formatting tool is provided in the toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

You can hook up stdin and stdout of processes together in python using Popen but it's usually easiest to let shell shell do the work, for example you can:

```
subprocess.check_output('ls | grep something', shell=True)
```

Related: [How do I use subprocess.Popen to connect multiple processes by pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295459/how-do-i-use-subprocess-popen-to-connect-multiple-processes-by-pipes)