# Python complex string interpolation on shell command

Tags: python, string, ffmpeg, subprocess

I have a shell command that I would like to execute, with a python script. It's a combination of `ffmpeg`, `grep`, `gawk` and several other `ffmpeg` options.

**The command**

```
ffmpeg -i http://0.0.0.0:8080/stream/video.mjpeg -vcodec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 2 -loglevel 40 -segment_format mp4 capture-%05d.mp4 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered -Eo "segment:.+ended" | gawk -F "'" '{print $2; system("")}'
```

If you run this command on terminal, it should return a string

```
capture-00001.mp4
```

Now, my objective is to run this with `subprocess` on Python3. Since the command is rather complex with mixed single and double quotes, it needs to be treated correctly otherwise it will complain `EOL while scanning string literal`, `invalid syntax`, etc, etc.

I have tried several string formating methods but none work. Below is one of the ways I've tried.

**Script**

```
import os
import datetime
import subprocess

first = "segment:.+ended"
second = "'"
third = '{print $2; system("")}'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fScript = "ffmpeg -i http://0.0.0.0:8080/stream/video.mjpeg -vcodec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 2 -loglevel 40 -segment_format mp4 capture-%05d.mp4 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered -Eo {} | gawk -F {} {}".format(first, second, third)
    try:
        result = subprocess.check_output(fScript, shell=True).decode('utf-8')
        print(result)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(e.output)
```

Comment: The problem is that your command is not a single subprocess it's 3 (`ffmpeg` piped into `grep` piped into `awk`). If you want to replicate this with the subprocess module you could run all 3 as separate subprocesses and connect the pipes together.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295459/how-do-i-use-subprocess-popen-to-connect-multiple-processes-by-pipes for more info

Comment: @TomDalton Thanks for the link. Gonna study on it

Comment: Might have already tried it but you could try: `fscript = r"""ffmpeg -i http://0.0.0.0:8080/stream/video.mjpeg -vcodec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 2 -loglevel 40 -segment_format mp4 capture-%05d.mp4 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered -Eo "segment:.+ended" | gawk -F "'" '{print $2; system("")}'"""`

Comment: @NathanBlaine Your script works, but it does not print the result as intended, I'm guessing its the subprocess. Anyway, can you tell me what does the `r` do?

Comment: Yeah so `r` basically means raw string literal (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals). I think what might have made that work there was actually the triple `"` on each side of your command though

Comment: @NathanBlaine Thanks for the suggestion, I tried removing `"` on each side but it breaks the literal. I've made it work by using `subprocess.call` instead. Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion from @NathanBlaine, the use of marking string literal with `r` is exceptionally suitable for my use case here. Always happy to learn a new thing every day. :)

Though, I was not able to retrieve the string result with `check_output`. Instead, `subprocess.call` managed to return the expected strings. Here's the working code.

```
import os
import datetime
import subprocess


if __name__ == "__main__":
    fScript = r"""ffmpeg -i http://0.0.0.0:8080/stream/video.mjpeg -vcodec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 2 -loglevel 40 -segment_format mp4 capture-%05d.mp4 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered -Eo "segment:.+ended" | gawk -F "'" '{print $2; system("")}'"""
    try:
        result = subprocess.call(fScript, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True).decode('utf-8')
        print(result)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(e.output)
```